# A proof and explanation for why divisor classes pull back along flat morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite type morphism of noetherian normal schemes and let $D$ be a prime Weil divisor in $Y$. It seems to be a well known fact that if $\pi$ is flat, then $\pi$ pulls back Weil divisor classes in the sense that then is a morphism of abelian groups,
$$
\pi^*: \text{Cl}(Y) \longrightarrow \text{Cl}(X)
$$
defined on prime Weil divisor classes $\pi^{*}([D]) = [\pi^{-1}(D)]$ and extended linearly. I am having trouble finding an actual proof or explanation of this fact beyond just stating it is true in most algebraic geometry texts.

My attempt to prove it myself has just been via the going-down property for flat ring morphisms. Restricting to affines $\operatorname{Spec}A \subseteq Y$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B \subseteq X$ with $\pi(\operatorname{Spec} B) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}A$, if $\eta \in \operatorname{Spec}A$ is the generic point of a prime divisor then it corresponds to a height $1$ prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$. But then it seems like going-down only gives me that the primes in the preimage $\pi^{-1}(\overline{\{ \eta \}})$ must have height at least $1$. but surely this isn't enough to give me that it is a divisor. Is anyone able to tell me if I am even on the right track? I'm not even completely sure if going-down comes into it.

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: this produces better spacing. I've made the upgrade for you in this post for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the other inequality from dimension theory. In particular, we have the following theorem

> Let $\pi:X \to Y$ be a morphism of locally Noetherian schemes, and let $p \in X$, $q\in Y$ be points with $q=\pi(p)$. Then
> $$\operatorname{codim}_X p \leq \operatorname{codim}_Y q + \operatorname{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)} p$$

As you note, if we assume $\pi$ is flat, then Going-Down implies that we actually get an equality.

Finally, we apply this when $q$ is the generic point of a $D$ and $p$ is a generic point of an irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(D)$. In this case, we have $\operatorname{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)} p =0$.

Comment: For reference, this theorem appears as Exercise 11.4.A in [Vakil's 2017 Nov 18 notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/)

Comment: Thank you @Brian for the answer. I am still a little confused though. Let's forget flatness for a moment and just deal with the inequality. I may be slow but I'm not seeing how to apply the inequality for local rings to the case of closed subsets. In particular it's not clear to me why the generic point of $D$ must even be in the image at all. Certainly if any point in $D$ is hit by $\pi$ then the generic point will be in the flat case by going down. But what about in general? And even more so why would the generic point of a component of $\pi^{-1}(D)$ map to it?

Comment: If we drop the flatness assumption, then you are right, we could have that the preimage of the generic point of $D$ could be empty. I think this is the reason we only speak of *flat* pullbacks of Weil divisors: in general, Weil divisors do not pull back.

Comment: On the other hand, if $\pi$ is flat, then the premiage of the generic point of $D$ is exactly the set of generic points of irreducible components of the preimage of $D$.

Comment: But why does one inequality hold even without the flatness assumption? I am having trouble seeing how to apply the local ring inequality to the codimension of closed subsets inequality.

Comment: To be more precise, with the notation as in the question, is there an inequality that holds between $\operatorname{codim}_{X}f^{-1}(Z)$ and $\operatorname{codim}_{Y}Z $ without the flatness assumption?

Comment: I suppose its worth pointing out that $\operatorname{codim}_X p = \operatorname{codim}_X \overline{\{p\}}$.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I still don't see how the inequality for the dimension of local rings helps us get an inequality between the dimension of $\operatorname{codim}_X f^{-1}(Z)$ and $\operatorname{codim}_Y Z$.